# Custom struct to add parametres

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need a little help, i'm working on a tableViewController

[image]

like you see in the image, and I have to add to all cells these parameters:

name(label), image, type(label), coordinate(map)

The problem is that with this function

```
class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!



    var place = ["Caffè Spagar", "Duks", "Posta station", "Barnum", "Elephant Club", "Cinema", "Space", "Andromeda", "Rodolf", "Devil Chair"]
    var rows = 0


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows
    }



    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: (place[indexPath.row] + ".png"))
        cell.myLabel.text = place[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)
    }
```

I can obtain only the name and the image, I know that I have to create a custom struct to all the parameters but I'm a little confused about it, can anyone do a code example of how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this hands on assignment which is quite similar to your requirement.  Here is the whole problem statement and project

Problem Statement:
Create a simple iOS app with the below specifications.

Main Screen:
On App launch, user will be able to see a list of employees sorted alphabetically by name. Each entry in the list will show the employee name, employee designation and the profile picture of the employee (show a default image). Also differentiate the employees with designation as ‘Developer’ with a grey background shade.

Detail Screen:
Clicking on any employee in the list should take him to the employee detail page.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-w5Nhpy8tOwcXNmQXdnU2hDZEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please approve the answer once your requirement is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass UITableViewCell, create a prototype cell in your tableViewController in Interface Builder, set the type of your prototype cell to your custom UITableViewCell class, create all UI elements in the prototype cell, than link them to your custom class.